# uploading images through php forms in hostinger database?

Tags: file-upload, web-hosting, file-handling, image-upload

can we upload images to hostinger hosting database from an php Form and store it in hostinger folder.
actually i tried to do so .and i got result while working on localhost but as soon as i hosted it on hostinger i got no result.

**This is My code..**

```
<?php
// Include the database configuration file
include 'dbConfig.php';
$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){          
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");

            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            } 
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am a professional developer and I use hostinger for hosting therefore I just a few days ago also faced this problem, but today I resolved it:
Here is the code:
Hope it works:

```
<?php 
$d=$_FILES['file'][tmp_name'];
$a=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_FILES['file']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($d,$a)){
echo 'Successful';
}
else{
echo 'It was not successful';
}?>
```